# VerticalGridFragment title weird position

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I'm playing around with `leanback-v17` and I have a strange bug.

The title of a `VerticalGridFragment` should be positioned to the right, as in this example from [googlesamples/leanback-showcase](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase):

[image: VerticalGridFragment in leanback-showcase app]

But in mine it looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand why the title is located here and not to the right

I placed all the relevant (I hope) files in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/czak/df2e8ebd1e19d9d85dc6ddb36b04350b).
What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I resolved the issue by removing the `android:supportsRtl="true"` attribute from `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**EDIT**: This was a bug in the leanback library. See [Issue 213461](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213461). The bug has been resolved in support library v24.1.0. You no longer need to remove `supportsRtl` from the manifest.